# Celery returns no results when using node-celery(MeteorJS) and ampq backend

Tags: python, node.js, meteor, celery, amqp

I just started using Celery, where a Celery worker is written in Python, and the tasks are sent from node/Meteor using `node-celery`.

Why is there no `result` returned from the `client.call()`? Python worker console shows that the task has been sent and successfully processed. But none of the events `ready` and `pending` seems to be firing!

*Using Celery 3.1.7, RabbitMQ 3.2.2, node-celery 0.1.1, Meteor 0.7.0.1*

**Node**

```
var celery = Meteor.require('node-celery'),
    client = celery.createClient({
        CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'amqp://',
        CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER: 'json',
        CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER: 'json'
    });

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected')

    var results = client.call('tasks.echo', ['Hello world'], function(result) {
        console.log('results:' + result);
    });

    results.on('pending', function(result) {
        console.log('pending: ' + result)
    });

    results.on('ready', function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    });
});
```

**Output**

```
Connected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

You now can find my [celery package](https://atmospherejs.com/package/celery) on atmosphere, or just install with `mrt install celery`

---

I've been through the pain of setting this up, but have come out the other side.

I endend up having to branch `node-celery` (https://github.com/nathan-muir/node-celery), and `node-amqp` (https://github.com/nathan-muir/node-amqp) to create workable versions.

I have bottled all this in to a meteor package - but I'm yet to clean everything up for general consumption. (https://github.com/nathan-muir/meteor-celery). I'd like to wrap it with Fibers/Futures instead of leaving it callback style (pull requests welcome.

The package reads from `Meteor.settings.celery`, so create a settings file like:

```
{
  "celery": {
    "CELERY_BROKER_URL": "amqp://guest@localhost:5672//",
    "CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND": "amqp",
    "CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT": true
  }
}
```

And start meteor with `meteor --settings path/to/settings.json`

I also run my client & workers with events enabled (`celery worker -E --config=xx`), so I can use the celery monitoring tools (and my own custom cloudwatch stats monitor https://github.com/nathan-muir/celery-cloudwatch)

If you've got any more questions - feel free to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Meteor but I was having a similar issue with `node-celery`.  Hopefully this will help someone else that will stumble on this question.

In my case I was able solve it by adding the following in the celeryconfig.py file

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'

CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

My node-celery call from nodejs looked like this:

```
var client = celery.createClient({ CELERY_BROKER_URL: photobutikConfig.tracer.brokerURL,
                                   CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'amqp',
                                CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER: 'json'}),
        tracerRequestType = ['tracer.tasks', requestType].join('.');

    client.on('connect', function() {
        var result = client.call(tracerRequestType, [payload]);
        result.on('ready', function (result) {
            client.broker.destroy();
        });
    });
```